# Changing the type of a column used in other views

Tags: postgresql, view

```
create table base (name character varying(255));                                                                                                                                                        
create view v1 as select *, now() from base;                                                        
create view v2 as select * from v1 where name = 'joe';
alter table base alter column name type text;
```

Gives this error:

```
cannot alter type of a column used by a view or rule
DETAIL:  rule _RETURN on view v1 depends on column "name"
```

This is sort of annoying, because now I have to recreate all the views that reference the `base.name` column. It's especially annoying when I have views that reference other views.

What I'd love to be able to do is something like:

```
select recreate_views('v1', 'v2', 'alter table base alter column name type text');
```

And have the function get the view definitions for v1 and v2, drop them, run the code specified, then recreate v1 and v2. If I could use Ruby, I'd probably have the function take a function/block/lambda, like

```
recreate_views 'v1', 'v2' do
  alter table base alter column name type text
end
```

Is something like this possible? Are there utilities out there that do something similar?

Comment: `select definition from pg_views where viewname ='v1';` gives you the view definition

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this does what you want, though I moved the view list to the end of args to be compatible with VARIADIC semantics.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION recreate_views(run_me text, VARIADIC views text[])
  RETURNS void
AS  $$
DECLARE
  view_defs text[];
  i integer;
  def text;
BEGIN
  for i in array_lower(views,1) .. array_upper(views,1) loop
    select definition into def from pg_views where viewname = views[i];
    view_defs[i] := def;
    EXECUTE 'DROP VIEW ' || views[i];
  end loop;

  EXECUTE run_me;

  for i in reverse array_upper(views,1) .. array_lower(views,1) loop
    def = 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ' || quote_ident( views[i] ) || ' AS ' || view_defs[i];
    EXECUTE def;
  end loop;

END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: To be more complete, one could figure out how to query which views depend on the table(es) you're modifying and use that query instead f enumerating view names.  Gonna need to understand pg_rewrite | pg_rule to do that, I think.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I also have a couple postgresql functions that need to be drop and recreated as well. I think I could do that with a similar approach.

Comment: I think the views need to be created in the opposite order in which they were dropped (if some of the views depend on other views).

Comment: I edited the function to create in reverse order from drop. If the views depend on each other the call needs to specify them in reverse dependency order

Comment: Thanks! I think I edited your answer to include the same code seconds after you did.

Comment: BTW, this doesn't work if your views are in different schemas.

Comment: (Got around it by not doing the quote_ident stuff and pretending that people name things sanely.)

Answer (score 1):

an improvment would be to check before trying to drop view if it exists at all, otherwise you will get an error, so do like this :

```
for i in array_lower(views,1) .. array_upper(views,1) loop
    select definition into def from pg_views where viewname = views[i];
    view_defs[i] := def;
    IF def IS NOT NULL THEN
        EXECUTE 'DROP VIEW ' || schema_name || '.' || views[i];
    END IF;
end loop;   

    EXECUTE run_me;

for i in reverse array_upper(views,1) .. array_lower(views,1) loop
    IF view_defs[i] IS NOT NULL THEN
        def = 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ' || schema_name || '.' || views[i] || ' AS ' || view_defs[i];
        EXECUTE def;
    END IF;
end loop;
```